# How to acquire tar.gz file from github R package

Tags: r, github, package, tar

I need to acquire a tar.gz version of an R package from github. I'm not sure how that's possible. Downloading the package from Github results in a zip file.

For CRAN packages, I would do the following, using `ggplot2` as an example:

```
download.packages(pkgs = "ggplot2", destdir = "package")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tar.gz for a Github repo `account/reponame`, branch `branchname` can be found at

```
https://github.com/account/reponame/archive/branchname.tar.gz
```

Hat tip to [jeroen/curl](https://github.com/jeroen/curl), where this trick is noted as a way to install curl without going through devtools (which uses curl)

Comment: The other way is to clone the repo, then use `devtools::install` on it, ofc